# Reading multiple lines from input in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read multiple lines from console input, but I can't really figure out the way to do it. I made a code that reads only the first line and tried to loop that, but I couldn't figure out the way that works. Any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* readLine() {
    char* line = malloc(100), * linep = line;
    size_t lenmax = 100, len = lenmax;
    int c;

    if (line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (;;) {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;

        if (--len == 0) {
            len = lenmax;
            char* linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);

            size_t diff = line - linep;
            if (linen == NULL) {
                free(linep);
                return NULL;
            }
            line = linen + diff;
            linep = linen;
        }

        *line++ = c;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    return linep;
}

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%s", readLine());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I only managed to loop the function calling twice, which just means I will read only one line twice.

EDIT: I found a way to read code line by line, by doing all the work to the line immediately after its input (saving all I need before the next line is inputted), and tried to stop the while loop while its != '\n', but the loop won't stop, instead it just keeps printing the '\n' character (I keep getting blank lines). Any help on how to fix this?

```
// Same stuff here

int main() {

    char* temp = readLine();

    while (*temp != '\n') {
        char* temp = readLine();
        printf("%s\n", temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Presumably, the function should take an argument, `size_t n`, which tells you how many lines to read.  You then wrap a `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)` loop around your current loop.  I'd use `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c !!= '\n')` for the inner loop control; that avoids some lines of code.  You should consider using one of the line reading functions (`fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` perhaps — I assume that they're off-limits for the purposes of this exercise.

Comment: Since your function returns allocated memory, it is crucial that you save the returned value in a variable so that you can free the memory after you've used it (printed it in your example program).

Comment: Your revised loop doesn't stop because it looks for a line that contains only a newline, but your function never includes the newline in the output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will try the solution you sent, hopefully it works. For freeing the memory part, I'm supposed to make function that frees all allocated memory later, so I'm leaving it for later.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But when I run the program and press the enter without inputting anything it outputs the new line like it ignores the while statement.

Comment: It outputs the newline that's in `printf("%s\n", temp);` — if there was a newline in the string returned from the function, you'd have double-spaced output, but you don't. When you hit return, the output is just an empty string plus the newline from the format.  You could use `printf("[[%s]]\n", temp);` to see better what's in the string.  You could also use `printf("%zu [[%s]]\n", strlen(temp), temp);` to see the length as well as the data.  Look at the code in the `readLine()` function; where do you copy the newline into the string?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh yeah, you are right. Let me try to fix it, hopefully we can do it together.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Earlier I tried to do the code as you suggested in the first place, by counting lines first, but that way I only managed to do the input, count lines, then write the input again which isn't what is supposed to be done so I started looking for another solution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also, when you said I should wrap `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)` loop around my loop, which loop were you referring to? The one inside main or the one inside function?

Comment: The specification in the question "I am trying to read multiple lines from console input" is ambiguous.  Are you trying to read multiple lines in a single function call, or trying to read one line at a time, calling the line reading function multiple times?  I assumed the former in my first comment, but your code reads one line more or less OK (there are quite a lot of good points in the code — but reporting EOF isn't one of them).  Subsequent comments are mostly neutral between one line at a time an multiple lines at a time.  One line at a time is more usual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214226/discussion-between-ik4a-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm kinda stuck again.

Comment: Back to chat, then.